# How do I develop and use the CommonApplicationData special folder for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wix

I have a WPF application that stores resource files locally. The resources files are kept up-to-date using by a process that runs when the application starts. The resource files are updated often and are common for every user running the application, so CommonApplicationData is the best place to store these resource files.

I have 2 questions regarding the use and development of the CommonApplicationData special folder. First, if I am developing the application in Visual Studio, what will it use for the CommonApplicationData path? I don't want the resource files to be stored in CommonApplicationData because that's not the right place to store the files when the app is under development. The solution that I thought of is to have anything in the app reference the |DataDirectory| and then if the configuration is set to Debug, set the DataDirectory to the bin directory of the app. If the configuration is set to Release, set the DataDirectory to the CommonApplicationData\Company\AppName directory. Is this the recommended way to handle this?

Second, the CommonApplicationData directory needs to be writable by all users that run the application. Is this directory writable to all users? Looking at the folder security on my local machine, it looks like there is only read/execute permissions for users (windows 8.1). Do I need to set permissions to to the CommonApplicationData\Company\AppName directory when the application is installed using the windows installer (WIX)?

I tried searching for the recommended practices to use CommonApplicationData, but couldn't come up with the answers to my question.

Answer (score 1):

During installation, you should create a folder in CommonApplicationData. Usually the preferred folder structure goes something like this:

c:\programdata\Company\Product\MyApp.config

This contains the Applications DEFAULT settings. It is written to during install and normally is NOT written to again by a user. It is managed by IT or some other admin. So the user NOT being able to write to this is correct.

Your application should actually use the ApplicationData for writing.

C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Company\Product\MyApp.config

So if the default in a config is true and a user sets this value to false. The code will write to the user's config but the Common or Default config is not changed.

Your application should load the the configuration from ApplicationData first and if ApplicationData doesn't exist, load the config from CommonApplicationData.

Now, if you have a file that you want all users to change and all users to share, and one user changing it changes it for another user, I would simply make that file reside in CommonApplicationData and make it writeable by setting the permissions during your installation process.

Comment: For configuration I understand and agree with what you are saying. My application uses about 150MB of resource files (part drawings, PDFs, etc) that get updated from a web service in a background process when the application is started. This data is common for everyone running the application and I would not want to store or download 150MB for each user when the information is the same for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You claim you searched for answers and yet the second result on Bing (sixth on Google) when I searched for `CommonApplicationData` was an article on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData) which in first sentence mentions that Microsoft recommends storing data common to all users in `CommonApplicationData` special folder and create a CompanyName/ProductName subfolder for your data... The author proceeds to provide a class that can be used to set read/write permissions to all users for the CompanyName folder.

> When you need to store data common to all users of an application
> locally, Microsoft recommend using
> System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData.
> In addition they also suggest creating a sub folder here with your CompanyName and
> a sub folder in that of ApplicationName.
> The issue with this is the folders and files you create only have read/execute
> permissions for other users other than the creator. This means that they cannot be
> appended to or replaced by another user without UAC elevation.
>
> Whilst I understand the reasoning for this, in reality it creates a
> problem for a shared dynamic data store.
>
> The class below addresses
> this by setting read/write permissions to all users on the CompanyName
> folder and optionally setting read/write permissions of the
> ApplicationName folder on creation and sub folders/files inherit these
> permissions.

Comment: I have found articles referencing that, but was getting conflicting information on the permissions part of it. Also, I found nothing referenced on best practices for where the application data should be stored when developing and debugging the application in Visual Studio